# How to add new embeddings for unknown words in Tensorflow (training & pre-set for testing)

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I am curious as to how I can add a normal-randomized 300 dimension vector (elements' type = tf.float32) whenever a word unknown to the pre-trained vocabulary is encountered. I am using pre-trained GloVe word embeddings, but in some cases, I realize I encounter unknown words, and I want to create a normal-randomized word vector for this new found unknown word.

The problem is that with my current set up, I use [tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_table_from_tensor) to convert from words to integers based on the known vocabulary. This function can create new tokens and hash them for some predefined number of out of vocabulary words, but my `embed` will not contain an embedding for this new unknown hash value. I am uncertain if I can simply append a randomized embedding to the end of the `embed` list.

I also would like to do this in an efficient way, so pre-built tensorflow function or method involving tensorflow functions would probably be the most efficient. I define pre-known special tokens such as an end of sentence token and a default unknown as the empty string ("at index 0), but this is limited in its power to learn for various different unknown words. I currently use [tf.nn.embedding_lookup()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) as the final embedding step.

I would like to be able to add new random 300d vectors for each unknown word in the training data, and I would also like to add pre-made random word vectors for any unknown tokens not seen in training that is possibly encountered during testing. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

```
def embed_tensor(string_tensor, trainable=True):
    """    
    Convert List of strings into list of indicies then into 300d vectors
    """
    # ordered lists of vocab and corresponding (by index) 300d vector
    vocab, embed = load_pretrained_glove()

    # Set up tensorflow look up from string word to unique integer
    vocab_lookup = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
        mapping=tf.constant(vocab),
        default_value = 0)
    string_tensor = vocab_lookup.lookup(string_tensor)

    # define the word embedding 
    embedding_init = tf.Variable(tf.constant(np.asarray(embed),
                                 dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=trainable,
                                 name="embed_init")

    # return the word embedded version of the sentence (300d vectors/word)
    return tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_init, string_tensor)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code example below adapts your `embed_tensor` function such that words are embedded as follows:

- For words that have a pretrained embedding, the embedding is initialized with the pretrained embedding. The embedding can be kept fixed during training if `trainable` is `False`.
- For words in the training data that don't have a pretrained embedding, the embedding is initialized randomly. The embedding can be kept fixed during training if `trainable` is `False`.
- For words in the test data that don't occur in the training data and don't have a pretrained embedding, a single randomly initialized embedding vector is used. This vector can't be trained.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

EMB_DIM = 300
def load_pretrained_glove():
    return ["a", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"], np.random.rand(6, EMB_DIM)

def get_train_vocab():
    return ["a", "dog", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"]

def embed_tensor(string_tensor, trainable=True):
  """
  Convert List of strings into list of indices then into 300d vectors
  """
  # ordered lists of vocab and corresponding (by index) 300d vector
  pretrained_vocab, pretrained_embs = load_pretrained_glove()
  train_vocab = get_train_vocab()
  only_in_train = list(set(train_vocab) - set(pretrained_vocab))
  vocab = pretrained_vocab + only_in_train

  # Set up tensorflow look up from string word to unique integer
  vocab_lookup = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
    mapping=tf.constant(vocab),
    default_value=len(vocab))
  string_tensor = vocab_lookup.lookup(string_tensor)

  # define the word embedding
  pretrained_embs = tf.get_variable(
      name="embs_pretrained",
      initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.asarray(pretrained_embs), dtype=tf.float32),
      shape=pretrained_embs.shape,
      trainable=trainable)
  train_embeddings = tf.get_variable(
      name="embs_only_in_train",
      shape=[len(only_in_train), EMB_DIM],
      initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.04, 0.04),
      trainable=trainable)
  unk_embedding = tf.get_variable(
      name="unk_embedding",
      shape=[1, EMB_DIM],
      initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.04, 0.04),
      trainable=False)

  embeddings = tf.concat([pretrained_embs, train_embeddings, unk_embedding], axis=0)

  return tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, string_tensor)
```

FYI, to have a sensible, non-random representation for words that don't occur in the training data and don't have a pretrained embedding, you could consider mapping words with a low frequency in your training data to an *unk token* (that is not in your vocabulary) and make the `unk_embedding` trainable. This way you learn a prototype for words that are unseen in the training data.

Comment: I tried following the above approach. But despite fixing the trainable parameter as false for predefined embeddings, they got changed during the training. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49488946/2061991

Answer (score 3):

I never tried it but I can try to provide a possible way using the same machineries of your code, but I will think of it more later.

The `index_table_from_tensor` method accepts a `num_oov_buckets` parameter that shuffles all your oov words into a predefined number of buckets.

If you set this parameter to a certain 'enough large' value, you will see your data spreads among these buckets (each bucket has an ID > ID of the last in-vocabulary word).

So,

- if (at each lookup) you set (i.e. `assign`) the last rows (those corresponding to the buckets) of your `embedding_init` Variable to a random value
- if you make `num_oov_buckets`enough large that collisions will be minimized

you can obtain a behavior that is (an approximation of) what you are asking in a very efficient way.

The random behavior can be justified by a theory similar to the hash table ones: if the number of buckets is enough large, the hashing method of the strings will assign each oov word to a different bucket with high probability (i.e. minimizing collisions to the same buckets). Since, you are assigning a different random number to each different bucket, you can obtain a (almost) different mapping of each oov word.

Answer (score 0):

An idea I had for this was to capture the new words to the pre-trained embedding by adding a new dimension for each new word (basically maintaining the one-hot nature of them).

Assuming the number of new words is small but they're important, you could for instance increase the dimensions of your embedded results from 300 to 300 + # of new words where each new word would get all zeros except 1 in it's dimension.